# How to get collaborators for each private repository for a personal plan in GitHub via API?

Tags: github, github-api

I have a GitHub personal paid plan and I have 20+ private repositories and also added collaborators on all those private repositories.

I can go to each individual repository and look at the collaborators list but is there a API available to

1. List all the collaborators for each private repository in my account
2. List all the private repositories in my account for a given username?

I know that it will be easy to handle these kind of scenarios in organizational account but currently I don't have any plans to convert into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [list collaborators for a repository](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/#list). If your repository is `user/2624242`, for example, then the request would look something like

```
GET /repos/user/2624242/collaborators
```

You can also [list your own repositories](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-your-repositories) and specify the type to list. This would look like

```
GET /user/repos?type=private
```

Both of these endpoints require that you be [authenticated](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/) though.

Comment: I also would like to know my second question. I did not frame my question properly I guess, I need to list all my repositories for a given collaborator username. Say for instance, user1 and user2 are collaborators for repo1, repo2, repo3. I would like to list all the repositories for user1

Comment: Repos for `user1` should simply be `GET /users/user1/repos` but if you want the intersection you'll have to get both users repos and compare them. Then again, I could still be misunderstanding your question